# Specify Map in Java generics

Tags: java, generics

I have the following interface:

```
public interface IGenericCache<K, V> {

    void put(K key, V value);

    V get(K key);

}
```

Then I want to create a concrete class that takes `CacheKey` object as input and `Map<String, List<String>>` object as output. A **conceptual** example is as follows:

```
public class LocalCache<CacheKey, Map<String, List<String>>> implements IGenericCache<CacheKey, Map<String, List<String>>> {

    @Override
    public void put(CacheKey key, Map<String, List<String>> value) {
        // TODO
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, List<String>> get(CacheKey key) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Where `CacheKey` is like:

```
@Data // lombok annotation
public class CacheKey {
    private final String attr1;
    private final String attr2;
}
```

I have seen red wavy lines from IDE by using the implementation in the example above. But I couldn't fin the correct format to match the generics `<K, V>` in the interface.

Could anyone good at Java please correct me? Thank you in advance!

Comment: You might consider looking at the JDK's Map interface and HashMap class to see an example of how to do this sort of thing.

Comment: @Charlie Thanks, I just took a look. We specify the key-value types in `Map<K, V>` when we create an instance, but on the other hand, how may I enforce the type when defining the concrete class? Is this not possible as interface uses `<K, V>` instead of concrete classes in `<>`?

Comment: Why limit the concrete implementation's types?

Comment: @Charlie I wanted to create a concrete cache class for a specific API, we have a couple of different APIs and each API has different caching implementation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By putting `<>` after the name of the class that you're defining, you're declaring tokens to be used as generics. But you don't want that, you just want to fill existing generic type arguments.

So just omit the first pair of `<>`:

```
public class LocalCache implements IGenericCache<CacheKey, Map<String, List<String>>>
```